# Why the difference between char* and char[x] matter when using the & operator

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The following code will segfault.

```
char* input = "12.34"; //< this is only to simplify the example.

char buffer[30] = { 0 };
memcpy(buffer, input, strlen(input));

char* part1 = strsep(&buffer, ".");
```

The following code will not.

```
char* input = "12.34"; //< this is only to simplify the example.

char buffer[30] = { 0 };
memcpy(buffer, input, strlen(input));

char* ptr = buffer; //< Only diff.
char* part1 = strsep(&ptr , ".");
```

When passed by reference (`&`) as a function argument, why does the difference between `char**` and `char*[30]` matter?

Comment: The first type is not `char*[30]` but `char (*)[30]` (pointer to array, not array of pointers). And it is completely different from `char**` (pointer to pointer).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the man for strsep, it needs the double pointer because it tries to assign the pointer.

```
"char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim);
...
and *stringp is updated to point past the token"
```

Basically if you have an array, you can't just tell the head of the array to be in a new place.  You can however make a pointer to any element in that array and then change the value of the pointer (thereby making it point to a different element if you so wish).